# Is there to make a table undroppable and/or unchangable when it's referenced by a given/any function or stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

Pretty much what the title says.

I would like to know whether there are ways of preventing tables from being dropped and/or changed if they're referenced by a specified (or any) function/stored procedure/trigger etc. so the risk of breaking a procedure is lowered.

I'm a complete beginner so I cannot really ask more specifically. Sorry.

Comment: You could lock it?

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way to do this would be to not grant `DROP` privileges to the account(s) that will be accessing the database. Generally it is a good idea to limit application accounts to just the operations they will need, as this can limit potential damage if a system is compromised.

For example:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SHOW DATABASES,
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, 
      SHOW VIEW
   ON `{database}`.* TO 'appAccount'@'%';
```